# How to convert this Date string into a long?

Tags: java, date, time

I am having issues converting a String that has this format for date from the server into a long?

```
Example Date String - "2016-07-04T00:02:34.457Z" (Note this is a string)
```

I tried this below but needs try catch around `gmt`, when I add it and a not null around `cmtDt` - then I initialize `cmtDt` to 0 pre setting it on the bottom and it is always 0.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = c.getTimeZone();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
formatter.setTimeZone(tz);
Date gmt = formatter.parse(comment.getDateCommented());
cmtDt = gmt.getTime();
```

Answer (score 3):

First, your input `String` includes milliseconds (and your format does not). Second, your input `String` includes a literal `Z` (which is presumably to indicate a UTC timezone). Finally, getting your system timezone and assigning it to the `formatter` isn't reliably going to be `UTC`. You need something like,

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
try {
    Date gmt = formatter.parse("2016-07-04T00:02:34.457Z");
    long cmtDt = gmt.getTime();
    System.out.println(cmtDt);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which I ran, and got

```
1467590554457
```

Comment: I tried this code, getting a 0 now, @Jason's code above worked just not the timezone aspect

Comment: @Lion789 Note that my code (if you copied and pasted then tsk-tsk) makes `cmtDt` local to the try block (and thus it would shadow any other `cmtDt` you have). Finally, try a debugger.

Comment: Local? I have cmtDt set outside of it if that should not work then?

Comment: And my code has `long cmtDt = gmt.getTime();`, which is another variable named `cmtDt`. Edit your post into a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: However thank you I have combined your timezone method with the Formatting @jason provided and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Your format string for the SimpleDateFormat needs to be:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");
```

My test code that works is:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = c.getTimeZone();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");
formatter.setTimeZone(tz);
Date gmt = formatter.parse("2016-07-04T00:02:34.457Z");
long cmtDt = gmt.getTime();
System.out.println("cmtDt = " + cmtDt);
```

Comment: Timezone does not seem to work, trying to have it locally affect and it is showing a future date... am I adding that wrong then

Answer (score 0):

The format in SDF needs to be fixed. The following will help you.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone tz = c.getTimeZone();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    formatter.setTimeZone(tz);
    Date gmt = formatter.parse("2016-07-04T00:02:34.457Z");
    long cmtDt = gmt.getTime();
    System.out.println(cmtDt);
```

Prints : 1467599640457